# UIActionSheet throws ViewController actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using XCode 5.1.1 for development purposes and using the iOS simulator to test my app. 
I have an action sheet that has Save, Cancel and Delete options. I haven't yet coded the action handling for Save and Delete, but tapping on cancel should go back to the previous screen (I have used navigation controller to move between screens). But tapping on cancel, throws me "**ViewController actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance**" error, which I am not able to solve. I have hooked up all the elements to their outlets/actions correctly. Below is my code. Please help. (I am trying to display the action sheet when a "return" button is clicked. And in the action sheet, when I tap cancel, the previous screen had to be displayed - I guess this can be done by dismissViewControllerAnimated which dismisses the current controller and displays the previous controller.)

```
 -(IBAction)returnModalAction:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: NULL];

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"What do you want to do with the user values?"
                    delegate:self
                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                    destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete"
                    otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];
    actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}


-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{


    if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        NSLog(@"You have pressed the %@ button", [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On your method returnModalAction: you are dismissing the view, so the garbage collector will release all the references of self(the view controller) in memory that's why when you try to to show the action sheet `[actionSheet showInView:self.view];` you get the error because the reference in memory doesn't exist.

So what you have to do is to perform `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: NULL];` when you actually want to display the previous screen, in your case that would be on the actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex: method, based on the index of the button.

Comment: FYI, there is no garbage collector in Swift and/or Obj-C. There is ARC which IS NOT a garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks a lot, marcos1490, your answer helped me solve the problem. I get a better understanding now. Thanks!